# apt-show-versions displays error of "Use of uninitialized value..."

Tags: apt

When daily Cron runs apt-show-versions the following error is displayed.

```
/etc/cron.daily/apt-show-versions:
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 586, <FILE> line 174.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 587, <FILE> line 174.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 586, <FILE> line 174.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 587, <FILE> line 174.
```

Here is a snippet in the area of line 586:

```
551 sub parse_file {
552     my ($file, $status) = @_;
553     my ($key, $value, $package, $packages);
554 
555     my $release = &determine_pkgfile_release($file);
556     open FILE, $file or &die("Can't open file $file: $!\n");
557     if ($opts{'verbose'}) {print "Parsing $file...";};
558     while (<FILE>) {
559         if (/^$/){
560             unless (defined $package) {next};
561 
562             if ($status) { # Are we parsing the status file?
563                 # if we did not specify a package or pattern
564                 # only include installed packages
565                 unless ($mode == $MODE_ALL and
566                         ($package->{$STATUS} =~ /not-installed|config-files/ or
567                          # don't print holded packages if requested
568                          ($opts{'nohold'} and $package->{$STATUS} =~ /hold/))) {
569                     $packages->{$package->{$PACKAGE}}{$package->{$ARCH}} = $package;
570                 }
571             }
572             else {
573                 if (!defined $packages->{$package->{$PACKAGE}} or
574                     !defined $packages->{$package->{$PACKAGE}}{$package->{$ARCH}}{$VERS} or
575                     $vs->compare($packages->{$package->{$PACKAGE}}{$package->{$ARCH}}{$VERS},
576                          $package->{$VERS}) < 0) {
577                     $package->{$RELEASE} = $release;
578                     $packages->{$package->{$PACKAGE}}{$package->{$ARCH}} = $package;
579                 }
580             }
581             undef $package;
582             next;
583         }
584         unless ((/^Package/) || (/^Version/) || (/^Status/) || (/^Source/) || (/^Architecture/)) {next};
585         ($key, $value) = split /: /, $_;
586         $value =~ s/\n//;
587         $value =~ s/\s\(.*\)$//; # Remove any Version information in ()
588         $package->{$key} = $value;
589     }
590     if ($opts{'verbose'}) {print " completed.\n"};
591     close FILE;
592     return $packages, $release;
593 }
594
```

I have searched and found similar (but different) topics with solutions that I'm not sure would work. Thanks in advance for help.

EDIT Code from `/var/lib/dpkg/status`as requested from @meuh

```
162 Description: Micro string library: shared library
163 ustr (Micro string library) is a string API for C. It has tiny overhead over
164 just plain strdup(), is much safer, is easier to use, is faster for many
165 operations, can be used with read-only or automatically allocated data. You
166 don't even need to link to the library to use it (so there are no
167 dependencies).
168 .
169 This package contains the shared library for ustr.
170 Homepage: http://www.and.org/ustr/
171 Original-Maintainer: Vaclav Ovsik <vaclav.ovsik@i.cz>
172
173 Package: libpam-winbind
174 Status: install ok installed
175 Priority: optional
176 Section: net
177 Installed-Size: 204
178 Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
179 Architecture: amd64
180 Multi-Arch: same
```

Comment: I replaced your code example with the same, viewed with `less -N` to get line numbers. Since it's perl script, you could run it under the Perl debugger, with `perl -d $(type -p apt-show-versions)`, set a breakpoint at  line 555 and examine `$file`. I think your problem is caused by Bad Data at line 174 of whatever FILE is being read at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

On my system the command is reading file `/var/lib/dpkg/status` and this is the one where line 174 is in an unexpected format.

The perl script `apt-show-versions` is expecting lines which begin with the keywords as in this example:

```
Package: x11vnc-data
Version: 0.9.13-1.1
Status: install ok installed
Source: x11vnc
Architecture: all
```

These keywords all have `:` following them, but on your error line this is not the case so the perl script instruction:

```
($key, $value) = split /: /, $_;
```

sets $value to undefined and so the next instruction:

```
$value =~ s/\n//;
```

cannot do a substitute, and generates a warning message.  I dont think this will break anything. It depends what the keyword was.

Look in the `/var/lib/dpkg/status` for the name of the package at fault, (line beginning `Package:` and add it and a few lines around the error line to your original post.

Comment: I added the info from '/var/lib/dpkg/status', There is a ':' following the keyword on line 174. Any other ideas?

Comment: Indeed, line 174 looks ok with a colon and a space in it, so the split should work. I can only suggest you make sure there are no non-printing characters in the line. e.g. do: `sed -n 174p /var/lib/dpkg/status|cat -vt` and you should see no difference if the line is ok.

Comment: Ran your code and returned `Status: install ok installed` which is exactly what should be returned. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you run `apt-show-versions -v` the `-v` should print `Parsing ` and the name of the file it is reading. I've assumed only `/var/lib/dpkg/status` is read, but perhaps another file is read too. Check if there are several "Parsing" messages.

Comment: I tried `-v` and it didn't list the file(s) being parsed. It created a list of all the packages installed, its version number, status. The status was `uptodate` or `installed: No available version in archive`. Only three had the "no version" status.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same errors. 
`/usr/bin/apt-show-versions -iv` showed the files it was parsing. In the file after the errors I found that it contained `:<tab>` instead of `:<space>` .